# ColdFusion loop only show div for the first loop

Tags: loops, coldfusion

I am using a ColdFusion loop and was wondering if there is a way to have a piece of code in the loop that will only show up for the first loop and not for any of the remaining loops. Where I see an issue with this could be is if there is only one loop it should still show. Is there a piece of code that does this like this code (`<cfif Add NEQ session.checkout.quantity.pcount>`) removes code from looping on the last loop?

This is how my loop looks:
`<cfloop index="Add" from="1" to="#session.checkout.quantity.pcount#" step="1">`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, just check it's the first loop.

```
<cfloop index="Add" from="1" to="#session.checkout.quantity.pcount#" step="1">
  <cfif Add EQ 1>
    show for first iteration only
  </cfif>
  all iterations
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Of course its that simple I tried so many things close to that! But was thinking it was more difficult. haha Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 2):

If (and it may not be) it's at the beginning of the first or end of the last iteration, why bother including the CFIF in the loop at all?

```
<cfif session.checkout.quantity.pcount gt 0>
  <div>...start content...</div>
</cfif>
<cfloop....>
  ...
</cfloop>
<cfif session.checkout.quantity.pcount gt 0>
  end content, as an example
</cfif>
```

Simple ifs run ridiculously fast fast, you probably can't even measure a difference between this method and containing within the loop but some sometimes small changes can make dramatic increases in performance.

Plus, it makes it slightly easier to read.